# Delphi: Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset (XE6)

Tags: sql, database, delphi, dataset, syntax-error

I have a little piece of code that gets a corresponding value from database when one is entered, that is, in a database like this

```
Code     Name

 1        A

 2        B

 3        C
```

When you enter 1 in the code area, it returns A, and if you enter B in the Name area, it returns 2.

I can get this to work just fine with the following code but an error message would pop out showing "Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset"

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

```
procedure TStock_Bookkeeping.Stock_Code_ValueChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Price_Per_Share_Value.Text := GetCurrentPrice(Stock_Code_Value.text);
  ExecuteSQL_CodeToName(Stock_Code_Value.Text);
end;

procedure TStock_Bookkeeping.Stock_Name_ValueChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ExecuteSQL_NametoCode(Stock_Name_Value.Text);
end;

procedure TStock_Bookkeeping.ExecuteSQL_CodeToName(const inCode: string);
var
  query : TFDQuery;
begin
  query := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    ConnectToSQLite;
    query.Connection := FDConnection1;
    query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Code_Name where Code =' + '"' + inCode + '"' ;
    query.Active := True;
    query.Open();

    while not query.Eof do
    begin
      Stock_Name_Value.text := query.FieldByName('Name').AsString;
      query.Next;
    end;
  finally
    query.Close;
    query.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;

procedure TStock_Bookkeeping.ExecuteSQL_NameToCode(const inName: string);
var
  query : TFDQuery;
  memTable : TFDMemtable;
begin
  query := TFDQuery.Create(nil);
  try
    ConnectToSQLite;
    query.Connection := FDConnection1;
    query.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Code_Name where Name ='+'"'+ inName+'"';
    query.Active := True;
    query.Open();

    while not query.Eof do
    begin
      Stock_Code_Value.text := query.FieldByName('Code').AsString;
      query.Next;
    end;

  finally
    query.Close;
    query.DisposeOf;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: We can't see your screen from here - which line *exactly* do you get the error message on?

Comment: I do not have any error while compiling, and I actually get the result on runtime, except I get the "Cannot perform this operation on a closed dataset" message pops out...
Thanks for replying :)

Comment: I wouldn't set `Active` property. I would just assign a connection, SQL query and call `Open`. Also, there's no need to not call `Close` in the `finally` block. If an exception would be raised (and the dataset won't open), you'll be closing a closed dataset. Besides, take the time to learn how to use parameters. Your code is now vulnerable for SQL injection.

Comment: At which line of code does the error message pops up when you step through te code?

Comment: Please make sure you edit your q to answer Copilot's comment.  Also I don't follow what you're trying to do in your "while not query.eof" loops - you seem to be overwriting the .text property of your Stock_Name_Value and Stock_Code_Value by *each* row's field values, not just one of them.

Comment: Why are you using both `Active := True` (which opens the query) and `Open;` (which tries to open the already opened query again)?

Comment: Thank you for your replies, I have now taken out the 'Active := True' line.  

I have tried debugging by comment out one of the OnChange Event, and now the error no longer pops.  So I think it's like @TDC said that the two OnChange events are interfering with each other.  However, I still do not know how to solve the problem...

Comment: The "Not enough actual parameters" is unlikely to have anything to do with the answer below.  Meanwhile, you have not supplied the extra info requested.

Answer (score 1):

Set a breakpoint and walk the code (F7):

If the `Stock_Code_ValueChange` event is connected to the `Stock_Code_Value` edit box when you change the value of `Stock_Code_Value.Text` you are changing the value of `Stock_Name_Value.Text` which then fires the `Stock_Name_ValueChange` event but you have not completed the `Stock_Code_ValueChange` event.

Add a `Stock_Name_ValueOnChange := nil` as the first line of the `Stock_Code_ValueChange` procedure and a `Stock_Name_ValueOnChange := Stock_Name_ValueChange` as the last line of the procedure to stop the `Stock_Name_ValueChange` event from firing while the `Stock_Code_ValueChange` event is processing.

Then do the opposite for the `Stock_Name_ValueChange` event.

Comment: Totally missed the independent query objects :-o But you may still want to make the changes I suggested.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions but after I tried it out, I get the
"Not enough actual parameters" error message.